# How to make in function query in linq to sql

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql

```
Select * from tablename where id in(1,2,3);
```

How to make this query by linq to sql.
I tried by using `Contains` method but it only works for one value not for multiple.

Answer (score 2):

Contains should work for multiple values.

```
var numbers = new List<int>{1, 2, 3};

var result = tablename.Where(m => numbers.Contains(m.Id));
```

Comment: ok thanks but i have a query like this `(from p in db.GroupItems where p.GroupID == groupID select p).ToList()` here `p.GroupID` is the primary key but now i want to modified that query like `(from p in db.GroupItems where p.StudentPhotoID.ToString().Contains(AllStudentID) select p).ToList();`,,here `AllStudentID` is string values contains 1,2,3.It works for single value but not for multiple,May you correct this query..

Comment: Could you show how AllStudentID looks like ? It's just a string, not an array ? Anyhow, you should make AllStudentID an array if it's not (using string.Split, for example), and use something like `GroupItems.Where(p => AllStudentID.Contains(p.SutdentPhotoID))`. Cause you need Enumerable.Contains, not string.Contains !